# How can I apply the view binding in adapter class in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am try to apply view binding in my project, I have like that adapter class, but I did not understand how I will apply. Any idea?

```
 class Center : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var binding: ActivityCenterBinding
var listView: ListView? = null
private var mTitle = arrayOf("Help", "Help2", "Help3")

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityCenterBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)

    listView =   binding.help_listView
    val adapter = MyAdapter(this, mTitle)
    listView!!.adapter = adapter

  
internal inner class MyAdapter(
    context: Center,
    private var rTitle: Array<String>,

) : ArrayAdapter<String?>(context, R.layout.row_center, R.id.textView_center, rTitle) {
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val layoutInflater =
            applicationContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val binding = ActivityCenterBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)

        val myTitle =   binding.textView_center


        myTitle.text = rTitle[position]
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

the problem is

> Unresolved reference: textView__center

and

> Variable expected

for text

Comment: Try this `val row = RowCenterBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)  val myTitle =   row.textViewCenter`

Comment: If you mean "how do I get the ``binding`` object", you do ``val binding = RowCenterBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)``: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments

Comment: @Zain, is it possible u answer question, it is same still

Comment: @cactustictacs, I saw this link before, but didnt work for me, is it possible u answer the question

Comment: I don't know what problem you're having, so I can't really answer it. That's how you inflate the binding class though!

Comment: @cactustictacs, it says, Unresolved reference: textView_center and Type mismatch.
Required:
View
Found:
RowCenterBinding, for return binding

Comment: Check this `val row: RowCenterBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(context),
                R.layout.row_center,
                parent,
                false
            )`

Comment: You need to return ``binding.root`` (which is the root ``View`` in the layout binding).  The ``unresolved reference`` bit sounds like you don't have a TextView with an ID of ``textView_center`` in ``row_center.xml``

Comment: @cactustictacs, I am update question according to ur answer, still same problem

Comment: Change the ``val binding`` line back to the one in my first comment, and make sure you have a TextView called ``textView_center`` in your ``row_center.xml`` file. You definitely don't want ``ViewDataBinding?`` in there

Comment: @cactustictacs, yes sure I dont want to ViewDataBinding

Comment: wait sorry, if your TextView's ID is ``textView_center`` I think it's named ``textViewCenter`` in the ``binding`` object. After you've inflated it, if you type ``binding.`` the code completion thing should show you all the view variable names

Comment: @cactustictacs, I update question with whole code

Comment: Now you've got two kinds of binding class and you're using the wrong one :/ look I'll post an answer, but like I said you want ``val binding = RowCenterBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)`` - you're inflating ``row_center.xml``, so you need to use ``RowCenterBinding.inflate``

Comment: @cactustictacs, ok I will wait ur answer tnx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use View Binding, each layout XML class generates a "binding" class named after it. So `R.layout.row_center` has a class called `RowCenterBinding` (underscores are removed, words are capitalised, and it ends with `Binding`).

You create an instance of a binding class by calling its static `inflate` method, like this:

```
// in an Activity
val binding = RowCenterBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
// in anything else - you pass the thing the View is being inflated into (parent)
// and whether it should actually be added to that parent (no)
val binding = RowCenterBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
```

Now you have a `RowCenterBinding` object. It has a `root` property, which is the view hierarchy you inflated (which you need to return at the end of your `getView` method in the question). It also has a property for every `View` with an ID in the XML file. (These get renamed the same way that `row_center.xml -> RowCenter` does.)

So you end up with a `binding` object that holds your `View`s (`binding.root`) and also references to the ones with IDs (`binding.textView1`, `binding.saveButton` etc.) That's pretty much it!

(If you already have a view hierarchy inflated from an XML file, like in an `Activity`, you can create the binding object from that with `RowCenterBinding.bind(view)`)

---

You keep editing the question and inflating different things, so just do this:

```
internal inner class MyAdapter(
    context: Center,
    private var rTitle: Array<String>,

) : ArrayAdapter<String?>(context, R.layout.row_center, R.id.textView_center, rTitle) {
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val layoutInflater =
            applicationContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

        // You're inflating row_center.xml, so RowCenterBinding is the class you want
        // Don't specify a type here unless you know what you're doing - this is fine!
        val binding = RowCenterBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)

        // this requires a view in the XML with an android:id of textViewCenter,
        // text_view_center, or something like that. Let autocomplete help you here!
        val myTitle =   binding.textViewCenter

        // this should work fine once myTitle is assigned to a TextView
        myTitle.text = rTitle[position]

        // this method requires an inflated View, so we return the root view
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Since you have a variable called `binding` in your outer activity too, you might want to call this one `rowBinding` or something instead, so you don't confuse them.

(Also you shouldn't need to do any of this for a basic `ArrayAdapter`, doesn't it Just Work if you delete the `getView` method? By default it should create a view and set the text on a TextView using the constructor parameters you're passing)

Comment: @castustictacs, tnx so much for ur answer, I will apply now

Comment: what a great answer, tnx so so much :)))))), u are great developer :)

Comment: no worries, hope it makes sense! It's easier when you get how it all works